# How to transform discrete choice data into binary indicators

Tags: r, set

I have some discrete choice data I'd like to try with the  [upSetR](https://cran.r-project.org/package=UpSetR) package, but can't figure out how to get my data into a usable form, which seems to require a set of binary variables for all the possible choices.

It consists of 4591 observations on sets of 8 choices, `c1:c8`, among elements of subsets, {1,2,3}, {4,5}, {6,7}, ... {19,20}. 
The data.frame `doors` looks like this and can be found [https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iffufkt3iz6guf/doors.csv?raw=1 here].

```
> doors <- read.csv("https://www.dropbox.com/s/8iffufkt3iz6guf/doors.csv?raw=1", 
                     row.names=1, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> doors$date <- as.POSIXct(doors$date)

> doors[sample(1:nrow(doors), 15), 1:8 ]
     c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8
3038  2  4  6  9 11 14 16 20
2021  2  4  7 NA 11 14 16 20
3482  2  4  7  9 13 14 17 20
4779  2  4  6  9 11 14 16 19
3922  1 NA NA NA 11 15 NA NA
1726  2  5 NA NA 11 15 NA 20
4659  2  4  6  9 11 14 16 NA
1267  3  4  6  9 13 14 17 20
3916  2  5  7  9 13 14 16 19
5132  3  4  6  9 13 15 16 19
1846  2  4  6 NA 11 NA 16 20
1768  3  5  6 NA 13 14 16 20
3833  2  4  6 NA 13 14 16 19
1610  2  4  6  9 11 NA 16 19
4290  1  5  6 10 13 14 18 19
>
```

I want to transform `c1:c8` in the `doors` data frame into binary variables, `d1:d20`, where for each
observation, `d[i] = 1` if `i` is included anywhere within the variables `c1:c8`.  How can I do this?

If it helps to understand this, the following table shows the relation between the choice variables (what I have) and the binary variables (what I want).

```
> tab <- table(stack(doors[,1:8]))
> names(dimnames(tab)) <- c("door", "choice")
> rownames(tab) <- paste0("d", 1:20)
> tab
     choice
door    c1   c2   c3   c4   c5   c6   c7   c8
  d1   382    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  d2  2193    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  d3  2016    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
  d4     0 2843    0    0    0    0    0    0
  d5     0 1155    0    0    0    0    0    0
  d6     0    0 2607    0    0    0    0    0
  d7     0    0 1349    0    0    0    0    0
  d8     0    0    0  654    0    0    0    0
  d9     0    0    0 2174    0    0    0    0
  d10    0    0    0  197    0    0    0    0
  d11    0    0    0    0 2093    0    0    0
  d12    0    0    0    0  367    0    0    0
  d13    0    0    0    0 1585    0    0    0
  d14    0    0    0    0    0 2449    0    0
  d15    0    0    0    0    0 1466    0    0
  d16    0    0    0    0    0    0 3004    0
  d17    0    0    0    0    0    0  354    0
  d18    0    0    0    0    0    0  591    0
  d19    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 1581
  d20    0    0    0    0    0    0    0 2092
>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this does what you're after. You use `apply` to look for a particular number in each row; you wrap that in a call to `lapply` that iterates it through the sequence from 1 to 20; you use `Reduce(cbind)` and `as.data.frame` to wrangle the list that produces into a data frame; and then you give the columns in that data frame nice names. In the call to `apply`, you can use `as.numeric(any(x == i))` to get a dummy variable indicating whether the value `i` appears anywhere in that row.

```
df <- lapply(seq(20), function(i) apply(doors[,1:8], 1, function(x) as.numeric(any(x == i, na.rm = TRUE))))
df <- Reduce(cbind, df)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
names(df) <- paste0("d", seq(20))
```

Here are the first several rows of the result:

```
> head(df)
    d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 d10 d11 d12 d13 d14 d15 d16 d17 d18 d19 d20
758  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
759  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
760  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0
761  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
762  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1   0
763  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1
```

Comment: That more or less works, except my `doors` data has a date column as well, so I use this on `dd <- doors[,1:8]` with my data set.

Comment: In this case, you don't need the `doors[,1:8]` part, because the values 1:20 don't appear anywhere in your date column. But, yeah, it's still probably a good idea to restrict the operation to only the relevant columns.